# Alarm clock unlocking device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, alarm, samsung-galaxy-tab-4, echo

I have a Galaxy S3 phone and a Galaxy Tab 4, both with the same issue. I'm using the Echo Lockscreen app (paid version) with a pattern unlock, which I'm happy with. I'm also using the built-in "Clock" on the phone and "Alarm" on the tab.

When the alarm rings and I shut it off, the phone/tab is unlocked - so it skips the unlock security. Using the stock Samsung lock screen, the lock works and I have to unlock the phone normally.

I'm not finding any settings either on the device or in the app - any ideas on how to fix this? I'd be willing to switch to a different alarm clock app, but I'd like to keep the lock screen unless there's something as good as this one.

I can switch Echo to use my system unlock method instead of its own, but the user experience is kind of crappy there - you have to unlock then also swipe away Echo.

If someone steals/finds my phone, I'd rather not have it unlock automatically for them if I don't remote-wipe it before 6am the next day.

**EDIT** I'll be getting a Galaxy S6 in a few days to replace the S3, but I'd guess it will have the same issue there as well - but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've found a security vulnerability in the Echo lockscreen app. You should contact their support and let them know about it as they will want to fix this.

Comment: Yep, I figured that, but it just seems like such a simple and common use-case that it's hard for me to believe they never considered this, and haven't heard about it already. If I don't find a workaround, I'll definitely report to the devs next.